# How to change the size of a showModalBottomSheet? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter

I am using a `showModalBottomSheet` widget and i want to changed the size so that it occupies about 75% of the screen (by default it seems to be occupying 50%). I tried to follow the documentation but could not find a size property. Could someone suggest me a method to change the size of this widget?

[currently looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5itin.jpg)

Comment: Please at least update with the code you've tried or make a quick sample for your scenario. This would help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- MediaQuery in Container or SizedBox
- Flexible, Expanded widgets in Column or Row Widgets
- Wrap, FractionallySizedBox widgets

Choose one of them which one is better for your architecture

```
       showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext builder) {
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height * 0.75,
              child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                initialDateTime: appointmentDate,
                onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDate) {
                  if (this.mounted) setState(() => appointmentDate = newDate);
                },
                use24hFormat: true,
                mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                isScrollControlled: true,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
```

Comment: This one seems to be occupying 33% of the screen. I tried to put a value less than one (i.e. 0.3) and the maximum size it occupied was 50% of the screen.

Comment: If you make isScrollControlled: true, modalBottomSheet height will be same with full screen height. You should wrap your content with one of the ways that I said in my answer. I add isScrollControlled: true and edited my answer.

Comment: got it! Thanks for helping out

Comment: I'm happy to helped you

Comment: Tried this. Only worked with `isScrollControlled` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 7):

wrap your layout children with a `Wrap widget`, then you don't have to set the height.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          isScrollControlled: true,
          builder: (BuildContext builder) {
            return  Container(
            child: Wrap(
              children: <Widget>[

              ],
            ),
          );
          },
        );
```

Comment: This used to work before, probably flutter 2.5 if i remember right. Once i upgraded to flutter 2.8, this does not work anymore. It adds somehow the first item in my list view to the content of the bottomsheet when it gets shown. weird.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the param *isScrollControlled* to true

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    /* your code */
  }
);
```

Comment: this will occupy the whole screen. I need it to occupy about 75% of the screen

Comment: @ user12372626 this isn't true. I had to set `isScrollControlled ` to `true` in order for the height calculation mentioned above (to `0.75`) to work correctly.

Comment: you can set isScrollControlled to true and then inside your modal container use Wrap widget

Answer (score 1):

This is full code, according to above answers:

````
final Map<String, String>? dictValue = await showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (context) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height * (3 / 4),
          child: MyCustomWidget(
            showPhoneCode: true,
            onSelect: (value) {},
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

To occupy 75% of screen,

```
showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext builder) {
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height* (3/4),
              child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                initialDateTime: appointmentDate,
                onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDate) {
                  if (this.mounted) setState(() => appointmentDate = newDate);
                },
                use24hFormat: true,
                mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
```

Comment: Tried this. Only worked with `isScrollControlled` is set to `true`.